# make random numbers from two lists in a base list

Tags: python, list, random, maya

```
import maya.cmds as cm
import random as rand
def vertQuery(List = [] , *arg):
    myList = cm.ls(sl = True)
    for i in myList:
        List.append(cm.ls('%s.cv[:]'%i, flatten = True))
    return List

a = vertQuery()

def randMaker(randList = [] , x = 0 , y = 0 ,*arg):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(len[x][y]):
            randList.append(rand.uniform(-1,1))
            y+=1
            if y == len[x][-1]:
            x+=1

b = randMaker()
```

the first function get the all cvs of curves and put them in a list

the second function read the len of lists in a base list and produce random number

but i get this error

```
# Error: line 1: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 9, in <module>
#   File "<maya console>", line 3, in randMaker
# TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__' #
```

i didn't use a class.

somebody tell me my script is correct or not?

best regards

Comment: What's up with `vertQuery`'s arguments? `List` has a mutable default value, and `*arg` is ignored.

Comment: i know. it has gui.they are for buttons

Comment: Your code and explanation has several problems. Fist things NEVER ever use variable name List it masks a built in class definition. Second your question Si a bit vague so its not clear what you want done. This means all the people answering are going to guess what you need, whereas you could help them help you better. Edit the question. **PS** no your script is not correct, len[x][y] is a call to a class but len is not a class with getattr

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple instances of `len[x]`. I don't know what you were expecting it to do, but that attempts to treat the built-in function `len` as a sequence or mapping and get the item indexed by `x` from it. That's not what you want.

Comment: i wanna make random numbers by length of lists in base list :

Comment: if i have a list with two lists in it and each list contains 10 numbers i wanna make 10 random number between -1,1 for list one and 10 numbers for list 2

Comment: suppose i have two curves, one with 8 cv another with 10 cv,,,   the first function get the vertices of each curves and put it in a list in a base list and after that i wanna make a random numbers by length of each list

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

*builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '**getitem**'* is because you're calling len[x][y] where x and y are integers. It's looking for an item inside of [x] at address [y] but x is an integer.

Do you mean you want as many items as there are elements in each list? in that case

```
randoms = [rand.uniform(-1, 1) for item in your_list_here]
```

or do you want to randomize the order of the items in the list?

```
from random import shuffle
random.shuffle(your_list_here)
```

Comment: the first one is ok but it makes two random number there are two lists  in a list, i need a code that produce for every item in these two lists or every items in lists and put them in the new list like below   myList = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]                                           newListthathasrandomnumberslikemyList = [[r,r,r,r],[r,r,r,r]]

Comment: def randList (lists, items):
    result = [] 
    for r in range(0, lists):

Answer (score 0):

```
def randList (lists, items):
    result = [] 
    for r in range(0, lists):
        result.append([ rand.uniform(-1, 1) for item in range (0, items)]
    return result
```

where lists and items are both numbers

If you need to support a random list of the same lenght for every input list:

```
import random as rand
def randList(incoming_list):
  return [rand.uniform(-1,1) for item in incoming_list]

lol = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
map (randList, lol)
# Result: [[0.69216923130579877, -0.14662937842796997, -0.34716966661973547], [-0.093984856291694729, 0.22759662550142301, -0.039570637016330457]] #
```

Comment: the first one is ok but it makes two random number there are two lists in a list, i need a code that produce for every item in these two lists or every items in lists and put them in the new list like below myList = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]] newListthathasrandomnumberslikemyList = [[r,r,r,r],[r,r,r,r]]

Comment: ar you sure about it?   it makes two number one for each list in base list

Comment: **randlList** takes one list as an argument.  The map call is calling **randList** on every entry in 'lol' (= 'list of lists') so if the data were set up as I had it with lol = [list, list] it should work as shown.  Note that the second example changes the contents of **randList**